# Python function telling me I sent two arguments when I only sent one

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I'm using Google's [webapp](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/webapp/) framework.

What I'm trying to do below is simply send the results of [query.fetch](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/queryclass.html#Query_fetch) to a function that will take the results and create a table with them.

```
class Utilities(): 
  def create_table(results): 
  #Create a table for the results....
```

variable `results` gets two results back from query.fetch

```
results = query.fetch(10) #This returns two results
util = Utilities()
util.create_table(results)
```

Then I get the error

> util.create_table(results) TypeError:
>   create_table() takes exactly 1
>   argument (2 given)

I had thought that `results` would automatically get passed by reference. Am I wrong?

Comment: I added indentation since we're dealing with a language where it matters.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The first argument is set implicitly by python when the method is bound to an instance. In this case util. When defining a method in a class, the first argument is usually named `self` and is the bound object.

```
class Utilities():
    def create_table(self, results):
         pass # more to come
```

Should work fine :)

Edit:
This also means, you can call such methods also when not bound to an instance (i.e. obj.fun()):

```
utils = Utilities()
Utilities.create_tables(utils, results)
```

Comment: To clarify a bit, change the create_table(results) to create_table(self, results)

Comment: Just wanted to explicitly say that the way the OP's method is currently defined, the parameter `results` is actually '`self`' with a different name.  It is actually a function that takes 0 (external) parameters

Answer (score 3):

It should be:

```
def create_table(self, results):
```

Indeed, self is always passed, but the method needs to know to receive it!

Answer (score 1):

The first argument passed to a method is the instance of the class. You must account for this when defining it.

```
def create_table(self, results):
```

Answer (score 1):

You should read up on classes. A method of a class get's (self) sent as the first perameter.

Change it to

```
class Utilities(): 
    def create_table(self, results):
```

Answer (score 1):

The first argument of each python class method must be an instance of the class itself.
As a *convention*, `self` is the keyword which is used to refer to the class instance. There's no reason to use a different keyword and it is strongly discouraged not to follow the `self` convention :).
When the class method is defined, the `self` argument must be included, however, when the class method is used, the `self` argument is implicitly present.

Example:

```
class C:
def cMethod(self, a1, a2):
    pass
[...]

>>> cinstance = C()
>>> cinstance.cMethod(x1, x2)
```

I just wanted to point out this two aspects :).
Bye.